# Data binding to BindableProperty results in error "mismatching type between value and property"

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding, maui, .net-maui

I'm trying to get the following to work within my .NET MAUI project.

I have a view `SettingView`, which has a `BindableProperty` of type string.

```
    internal class SettingView : ContentView
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty BoundObjectPropery = BindableProperty.Create(
                nameof(BoundObject),
                typeof(string),
                typeof(SettingView),
                defaultValue: "",
                propertyChanging: BoundObjectChanged,
                defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.OneWay);

        public string BoundObject
        {
            get => (string)GetValue(BoundObjectPropery);
            set => SetValue(BoundObjectPropery, value);
        }
    }
```

I can call this from XAML as follows:

```
    <local:SettingView BoundObject="LiteralString" />
```

The provided String is passed and can be used from the `SettingView`.

But when I try to pass a property from the view model with a DataBinding, VS refuses to build and I get an error

I have the following property declared in my view model

```
public string TestString => "Lorum ipsum";
```

> XFC0009   No property, BindableProperty, or event found for "BoundObject", or mismatching type between value and property

```
<local:SettingView BoundObject="{Binding TestString}" />
```

But when I use 'primitive' views, like a Label, it works just fine..

```
<Label Text="{Binding TestString}"/>
```

If I use type Object instead of type string, it does build and run, and I receive an object of type "Binding". But it seems I can't do anything meaningful with this object.

Intellisense does complain that there is 'No DataContext found for Binding 'TestString'", but that shouldn't be an issue since it doesn't know anything about the DataContext at compiletime when using MVVM.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: **First,** you use "TestString" two different ways. `BoundObject="TestString"` refers to a literal string,`"TestString"`, not to some property. Use this to prove `BoundObject` is declared correctly - use breakpoint to verify that string is received. **Second,** `Text` accepts any bound property, and applies `ToString()` to it; that is probably why it is more lenient. **Third, show the property declaration for TestString**. Something is wrong at that end.

Comment: **Fourth,** *"I receive an object of type "Binding""* doesn't sound right. What do you mean "receive"? What you want to see is the contents of `TestString`, not a binding object.

Comment: I understand the difference between "TestString" and "{Binding TestString}". I was trying to say the BindableProperty is getting data that way ( and is receiving the literal string "TestString" that way ). My intention is getting the data binding to work, so receiving whatever string is in the TestString property of the Viewmodel/datacontext

Comment: The property declaration in the VM is 'public string TestString => "Test";'  Again this works for other elements such as 'Label'. What I mean by "receive" is just that; when the BoundObjectChanged method is called it gets passed a NewValue of type 'Binding', whenever the type declaration of the BindableProperty is set to Object instead of string. I have edited the main post a bit to make this more clear

Comment: So far everything looks correct. Except, in `BoundObjectChanged`, I expect parameter `newValue` to contain the **value** of the binding, not the binding object itself. I expect `"Lorum ipsum"` (but perhaps I'm wrong). I'll do a test in a bit. Clean Solution?

Comment: Even if the type of the BindableProperty is object you would expect the string, instead of the binding object itself? I don't know what the expected behavior would be, but since the Label text property can do a ToString on any object my guess is that you are correct. Unfortunately it's not what is happening on my view. It's 03:20am over here, so I will provide a clean solution sometime tomorrow. Thanks for thinking along

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Froms the official docs [bindable properties: Create a property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/bindable-properties#create-a-property)

> The naming convention for bindable properties is that the bindable property identifier must match the property name specified in the Create method, with "Property" appended to it.

You made a typo `BoundObjectPropery` instead of `BoundObjectProperty` (same for BoundStringProper**t**y) that why you had the compilation error:

```
internal class SettingView : ContentView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty BoundObjectProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
            nameof(BoundObject),
            typeof(string),
            typeof(SettingView),
            defaultValue: "",
            propertyChanging: BoundObjectChanged,
            defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.OneWay);

    public string BoundObject
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(BoundObjectProperty);
        set => SetValue(BoundObjectProperty, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was indeed the problem. Stupid that I missed that typo. What I still don't understand is why it did build when the type was set to `object` instead of `string`. I would expect the same builderror since the name was still off. This threw me off a bit.